# Cartesian Product of Quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Let $A, B$ be groups and $C,D$ be normal subgroups of $A,B$ respectively. The question was proving $A/C\times B/D\cong (A\times B)/(C\times D)$; which can be solved with 1st homomorphism theorem.

However, I wonder $A/C\times B/D = (A\times B)/(C\times D)$.

My attempt is:

\begin{align}
 (A\times B)/(C\times D)=\{(a,b)(C\times D)\ | \ a\in A, b\in B\} \\ = \{(a,b)(C , D)\ | \ a\in A, b\in B\} \\ =\{(aC,bD) \ | \ a\in A, b\in B\} \\ = A/C\times B/D,
\end{align}
since $(a,b)(C\times D)=\{(a,b)(c,d) \ | \ c\in C,d\in D\}=\{(x,y) \ | \ x=ac, y=bd, c\in C, d\in D\}$

$=\{(x,y) \ | \ x\in aC, y\in bD\}=(aC,bD)$.

I think it is wrong, but I can't find wrong point in my attempt above, and can't think of any counterexample. Are there any errors in my attempt? Or can you please explain a counterexample of $A/C\times B/D = (A\times B)/(C\times D)$? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your solution is basically correct. The only thing: $(aC,bD)$ is a pair of set and is not equal to $$\{(x,y)|x\in aC,y\in bD\}=aC\times bD$$which is a set of pairs and $(a,b)(C\times D)$ is equal to $aC\times bD$. So $$(A\times B)/(C\times D)=\{aC\times bD|a\in A,b\in B\}$$ and is not $\textit{equal}$ to $(A/C)\times(B/D)$, but it is $\textit{isomorphic}$, with the isomorphism being $$(A/C)\times(B/D)\ni(aC,bD)\mapsto aC\times bD\in(A\times B)/(C\times D)$$

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you for your kind explanation.